# mongodb query to fetch data from each category

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I am working with mongodb-odm, I have a database of videos distributed according to categories like humor, opinion, prank etc.

For the homepage I need at least 5 videos from each category, Can a query be build to get 5 documents from each category?

What I have tried is to separate queries one by one for each categories which doesn't seem like a good idea.

```
public function fetchTopVideos(){
    $dm = parent::getDocumentManager();
    $res = $this->app->make('stdClass');
    $res->status = 0;
    $limit = 5;
    $videos1 = $dm->getRepository("Videos")->findBy(array("category"=>"humor"),array(),$limit,0);

    $videos2 = $dm->getRepository("Videos")->findBy(array("category"=>"opinion"),array(),$limit,0);

};
......
......
```

My Mongo Document looks somewhat like below code, except the actual document has many more fields.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c0866cbff0fa431d8b4567"),
    "title" : "Harsha Bhogle at IIM",
    "alias" : "harsha-bhogle-at-iim",
    "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/kaw_bKOkULM?autoplay=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1",
    "category" : "opinion",
    "tags":[
        "cricket",
        "IIM"
        ],
    "thumbnailUrl":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/kaw_bKOkULM/hqdefault.jpg",
    "logtime":"1449663691"

}
```

Even suggestion of a logic is appreciated!!

Comment: Can videos have multiple categories? Will the query have to account for videos appearing in multiple categories?

Comment: @inspired No, each video will have only one category!! Sry for the late reply

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your mongodb documents look like?

Comment: @inspired I have added a part of my document, for better understanding of the question, please, take a look.

 1 more thing I have decided to switch my DB to MySQL and will use doctrine ORM, But still I will need this in some project, today or later, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Currently, you would need to do a query per category. Consider voting for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377. I think that's pretty much the same idea.

Comment: There is a distinct DB command to find distinct data, that might be used, otherwise it can be achieved through aggregation.